# How are multiple images combined into a GIF?

Tags: gif

How are multiple images combined into a GIF? Is it possible to break them up once they are combined?

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: You can download the decoder logic and details from the following link - http://www.tune2wizard.com/gif-decoder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are extractable.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF) gives you a hint about the technology behind the fileformat.
[The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a nice way to edit and separate each frame (as layer for example)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should install a gif image editor. 
Yes it is possible to do so.